# Birthday Problem in Continuous time

Tags: probability, birthday

I encountered a practical problem and want a help (my Google skill fail T^T). Basically, this is a birthday problem in continuous space, is it hard to solve?

#### Problem Statement

`A computer has N cores and there are M tasks within a day. Each core can only process one job at a time and each take T seconds to complete. And tasks can arrive at anytime (continuous time) with uniform probability.`

*Q1.* Given N,M,T. What is the probability that the event of all cores being occupied (processing a task) happen during a day?

*Q2.* Given M,T. Find N such that P(not all cores being occupied) > 0.9, 0.99, 0.999, 0.9999, 0.99999?

If there are approximation methods, the background information is that T is small e.g. 0.1 second, and M is much larger 10^7.

Comment: These are results in [queueing theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_theory)  If you search on that you can find lots of information.

Comment: Tasks cannot "arrive at any time with uniform probability" because there is no way to assign probabilities to the set of all non-negative real numbers with uniform probability.  So you need to consider some other probability distribution, such as an Exponential distribution.

Comment: @awkward I should clarify that I assume all M tasks must arrive *within a day*, so it is not unbounded.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks! I borrowed a book from libbrary today. Queueing theory is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: This is a $G/D/1$ queue with a nontrivial interarrival distribution, so I suggest either using standard approximations from queueing theory or creating a simulation to estimate the results.